# j2ee configure hibernate config file for sqlexpress 2012 in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jdbc

i need to configure the hibernate.cfg.xml to connect to my sql express 2012.

i'm trying to do this with the hibernate wizard tool, but it does not connect at all..

in my eclipse project, right click on project New > Hibernate Configuration File (cfg.xml).
clicked on next, and then on "Get values from Connection".

new profile, and in the "New Connection Profile" windows, i selected "SQL Server".

next, in the Drivers drop down list, i clicked on the "New Deriver Definition" button and in the "New Deriver Definition" window and selected "Microsoft SQL Server 2014 JDBC Driver"

in the JAR list tab, i added the "sqljdbc4.jar" that i downloaded from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774).

...and in the property tab, i set the properties in this way...

[image]

After clicking OK, when i test the connection i get the following error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: La connessione TCP/IP all'host localhost, porta 1433 non è riuscita. Errore: "Connection refused: connect. Verificare le proprietà di connessione. Assicurarsi che un'istanza di SQL Server sia in esecuzione sull'host e accetti le connessioni TCP/IP alla porta. Verificare inoltre che le connessioni TCP alla porta non siano bloccate da un firewall.".
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:241)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2243)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:491)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1309)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:328)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:96)
at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.msft.internal.sqlserver.connection.JDBCSQLServerConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCSQLServerConnectionFactory.java:27)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

if i ping sqlexpress from command line is ok (ping sqlexpress)
the firewall is diseabled.
the tcp/ip connection is enabled from the sql server network management

Answer (score 0):

When we need to connect to sqlserver like sqlserveer express 2008/ 2012 we need to use that jar sqljdbc4.jar and write correct config for SQLServerDialect and that's all: ex. of config (config location should be on resource folder named hibernate.cfg.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.micro soft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">login</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">pass</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=sensors</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQL ServerDialect</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```